# Nodejs - How to find the index with two conditions, one condition being where a property exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
   "examples":[
      {
         "key":"value1"
      },
      {
         "key":"value1",
         "key2":"example"
      },
      {
         "key":"value1"
      },
      {
         "key":"value2"
      },
      {
         "key":"value2",
         "key2":"example"
      },
      {
         "key":"value2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to use findIndex to find where in the object that `key === 'value1'` **and** `key2` exists (so in this instance the index would be 1).
I've tried using something like `var x = examples.findIndex(({key}) => key === 'value1' && ({key2}) => key2)` but it's not working. How do I go about this? Any answers would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Try `examples.findIndex(({key, key2}) => key === 'value1' && key2)`

Comment: @Rashomon That's perfect. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

`examples` is a property of the data object, so you need to iterate over that array. `examples.findIndex` won't do anything.

You can then check to see if `key` has "value1" as a value, and that there is a `key2` in the object.

```js
const data={examples:[{key:"value1"},{key:"value1",key2:"example"},{key:"value1"},{key:"value2"},{key:"value2",key2:"example"},{key:"value2"}]};

const result = data.examples.findIndex(obj => {
  return obj.key === 'value1' && obj.key2;
});

console.log(result);
```